# FAQ deep-linking

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, site-faq

I ask you to insert `id` attributes ([definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id), [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name)) for each heading and paragraph on https://stackoverflow.com/faq within the `div.content-page`. These serve as specific link target anchors, allowing to correctly deep-link to a certain relevant portion of the FAQ.

For instance, change

```
<p>When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you…
```

to

```
<p id="accepted_answer">When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you…
```

Comment: This would almost make lists bearable if used properly

Comment: Obsoleted by restructuring of the FAQ page.

Answer (score 8):

YES! I hate not being able to link to sub-headings...

Not sure that paragraph-level linking is all that *necessary*, but it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: what are we, like, Dave Winer, who links every paragraph ever?

Comment: who? Link or it didn't happen...

Comment: Dave Winer kind of invented blogging. An example of what Jeff is talking about is http://scripting.com/stories/2010/08/06/isApplesFreezeoutOfFlashWo.html; every paragraph has a # after it to assist anyone who might possibly want to link to it.

Comment: Oh. Lame. I bet that guy uses Twitter. @mmyers.

Answer (score 7):

OK, I added lots and lots of anchors to the faq:

```
<a name="ask">
<a name="benice">
<a name="behonest">
<a name="login">
<a name="howtoask">
<a name="reputation">
<a name="reputation-gain">
<a name="reputation-abilities">
<a name="bounty">
<a name="close">
<a name="deletion">
<a name="flagging">
<a name="signatures">
<a name="editing">
<a name="promotion">
<a name="search">
```

and just for you, shog9, a bonus anchor.

http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/2624/anchor.png

Comment: You should have used `id` instead of `name`. `name` has been **removed** (not just deprecated) in HTML 5.

Comment: Jeff, please do it right. I specifically told about `id` attributes, and the page is still lacking a deeplink for *accepted answer*.

Comment: @daxim `<a name="howtoask">` covers this.. just link like so http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Wow, people still use <a name> for anchors? You already have <h2> tags, add an id="foo" attribute to them.

Comment: You are inconsiderate to my request because you think I do not know how to use a deep-link – even though that should be evident from what I wrote up the question – instead of taking my complaint at face value; and you are inconsiderate to Kop's criticism on the technical side (`id` attributes), too. This lowers your standing in my esteem. I give up. If by now you have not understood what the use case and purpose of deep-linking to this very specific part of the FAQ is, you never will.

Comment: @daxim see "linked questions" in the right hand column of this question. Is that what you meant? I don't think I ever understood that.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. Go to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86859 and see about that this patch is applied.

Comment: @daxim if you read the linked column I'm pretty sure the link there, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86826/can-we-have-permalinks-to-each-block-of-faq-pages-ui , is what you were talking about. Personally I don't have a problem with our HTML 4.01 Strict doctype, though..

Comment: Jeff, did you actually try out that JQuery snippet? I know I did. Fact: it does solve the problem described in this topic here. Go back to the top and read it until you understand it. It's not difficult. Try harder to stop making wrong assumptions because this greatly inhibits communication. Apply the patch.

Comment: @daxim -1 for complete lack of manners. Don't be rude. But @Jeff he *is* referring to per-paragraph deep-linking which indeed isn't addressed by that question.

Comment: @Jeff, any change the TOS could get anchors to? Like http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#subscriber-content? (Oh, that *is* HTML5, so `<h2 id=...>`'s rather than `<a name=...>` there for sure.)