# Can we have permalinks to each block of faq page's UI?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, faq-update-request, permalink

For example

[image]

A quick and dirty script for above would be

```
$("h2>a").each(function(){
    $('<a href="#'+$(this).attr("name")+'" title="Permalink">¶</a>')
    .appendTo($(this).parent());
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The revised faq has links to each section as desired.