# Please add anchors to the sections on the /legal page

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, legal

As a community moderator, I'm occasionally asked to take down content based on copyright.  Per policy described in [What should I do when I see copyright violations posted on Stack  theOverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114928) and [Should moderators enforce NDAs for software vendors?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94488), I am not authorized to act on these because of potential trouble with the DMCA.

Anna Lear's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394455/the-halting-porblem#comment-10364345) is a good example of such a reply:

> As a community moderator, I don't have the authority to judge whether or not this constitutes a copyright violation. All copyright violations should be reported to Stack Exchange, Inc. in the form of a DMCA takedown notice from a copyright holder.

but it lacks references to the source of this policy and to directions to issue said takedown.  This information is available in section 15 on https://stackexchange.com/legal, but it's way down on the page.  I'd prefer to link to this part of the document with a #anchor fragment identifier, like in the FAQ.  Unfortunately, this section has no such link:

```
<h2>15. Copyright Policy</h2>
```

This bare HTML is similar to the old FAQ, which was [edited to allow direct linking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42144/faq-deep-linking), [amended to make this process easier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86826/can-we-have-permalinks-to-each-block-of-faq-pages-ui), and [further improved with even more provisions for internal linking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95160/experimental-stack-exchange-faq-improvement-project).

Can we have a similar upgrade of `/legal`?  The sidebar table of contents, top-quoting, and collapsible sections are all nice features of the FAQ that would also serve well here, but the most important thing is the presence of anchors to each section.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114928/102937

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I was linking to the question, but I agree that it would be better to link to the actual policy answers.  Edited.

Comment: With the caveat that I don't actually *make* policy; I just *interpret* it. :P

Answer (score 3):

The legal/terms of service pages have been [updated to a full 'legal portal'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310321/295232), partially to be compliant with GDPR.

The new portal has, at least for the public and private terms of service pages, clickable anchors like https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing which will take you directly to the relevant section. Other pages have been sized down to easily readable chunks of 1-3 'monitor heights' long, so it looks like this is either [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) or obsolete.

[image]